# Unprojecting 2D Screen Coordinates to 3D Coordinates

Tags: 3d, mapping, 2d, coordinates, intersection

I was wondering how I would go about mapping 2D screen coordinates to a 3D world (specifically the xz plane) knowing:

-position of the camera

-equation of the screen plane

-equation of the xz plane

All I want to do is have the land on the xz plane light up when I hover the mouse over it.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your world is rotated and shifted such that the camera is at `x=y=z=0` (world coordinates), the world `z` coordinate increases away from the viewer (into the screen), and the projection plane is parallel to the screen and is at `z=d` (world coordinate; `d > 0`), then you determine screen coordinates from world coordinates this way:

`xs = d * xw / zw`
`ys = d * yw / zw`

And that's pretty intuitive: the farther the object from the viewer/projection plane, the bigger its `zw` and the smaller `xs` and `ys`, closer to the vanishing point of `xw=yw=0` and `zw=+infinity`, which projects onto the center of the projection plane `xs=ys=0`.

By rearranging each of the above you get `xw` and `zw` back:

`xw = xs * zw / d`
`zw = d * yw / ys`

Now, if your object (the land) is a plane at a certain `yw`, then,  well, that `yw` is known, so you can substitute it and get `zw`:

`zw = d * yw / ys`

Having found `zw`, you can now get `xw` by, again, substitution:

`xw = xs * zw / d = xs * (d * yw / ys) / d = xs * yw / ys`

So, there, given the setup described in the beginning and screen coordinates `xs` and `ys` of the mouse pointer (0,0 being the screen/window center), the distance between the camera and the projection plane `d`, and the land plane's `yw` you get the location of the land spot the mouse points at:

`xw = xs * yw / ys`
`zw = d * yw / ys`

Of course, these `xw` and `zw` are in the rotated and shifted world coordinates and if you want the original absolute coordinates in the "map" of the land, you un-rotate and un-shift them.

That's the gist of it.

Comment: I cannot thank you enough for this very comprehensive and understandable answer.

Comment: Actually I have a question:

my yw is known to be 0.
Therefore given your equation:

zw = d * yw / ys

zw will always be equal to 0. How do I account for this?

Comment: If ys=0 and you're looking from the point having its world y=0 (where your camera is in the setup), then you can't see the plane. ys must be nonzero if you want to see it.

Comment: Im not sure i understand your explanation. To flesh out my situation more clearly:

-My camera is placed in the absolute middle of my projection plane which is the xy plane (zw=0)

-My camera is 1000 pixels away from the projection plane (zw = -1000)

-My terrain is the xz plane (yw=0)

So, solving for xw for example we get xw = xs*0/ys = 0.

I apologize for not understanding your last explanation :/

Comment: I mean, if you're at a table, look straight at the wall/window behind it. You can still see the table's surface without looking down. Now, slowly squat down until you stop seeing the table's surface. You'll stop seeing it when your eyes are at the level of the surface. You'll only see a line, not the plane. That's the situation with ys=0 when the camera's y is also 0.

Comment: Obviously you need to have the object below or above the camera, just like your eyes should be above the table to see its surface.

Comment: Ahh I see now. So these equations only hold for when the cameras coordinates are y=x=z=0? Say this was not the case, would the equation be different?

Comment: If the cam isn't at x=y=z=0 (world), you rotate and shift all coordinates such that the cam moves to x=y=z=0 (world) and then the equations work. I specifically called this out as the condition for the math.

Comment: Gotcha. Thank you for your patience with me my friend! :) You have been a great help.